# Plot simple bar graph in DataDog

Tags: logging, visualization, monitoring, datadog, datadog-dashboard

I am really at beginner level in DataDog.
I have scheduled a cron which will generate data & will pass it to datadog as logs.
I am getting below logs in DataDog in the format in Event attribute section

```
{
  marks: 245,
  student_id: 1234567,
  percentage: 70
}
```

I wanted to plot graph on x-y axis such that student_id will be on X-axis and percentage will be on Y-axis

Here I was able to get close to my requirement-

1. create measure from log variables
2. create new dashboard & select top list
3. In (2) Graph your data section written query: Logs - measure: percentage, avg by: student_id, limit to: top 10

Here is what I was able to get
[image]
I have explored "Time Series", "Top List" graphs but did not found them useful for my case.

Since I am getting all entries once in a day I wanted to strictly refresh it daily

Is there any possible solution to plot such graph?